# ACE Editor AutoComplete for an Object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ace-editor

Let's say I have an object `foo` that has two keys `bar, baz`. I want to create a custom `getCompletions` so that when I have typed `foo.` then it shows `bar` and `baz`. How do I do that? The `prefix` variable in the callback only contains the very last key pressed.

In my real example, I'd need to make an AJAX call to get the keys of `foo` before doing this, that's why I need a custom auto completion.

Comment: Do you want to show the autocompletion with bar, baz when user enters foo with a "."?

Comment: @Harshapps yes. And I have `enableLiveAutocompletion` turned on too, so the autocomplete fires live whenever user presses keydown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the prefix in the **getCompletions**, you can bind the key "." and then build your wordList. You can make your wordList global and use inside getCompletions or once you bind the "." use this code to get the before item ie foo, and then insert the value into the editor.

For example, If we take wordList as a Global array, and then when the user enters foo. we can add both the words into the wordList and then use in the Autocompleter.

```
editor.commands.addCommand({
    name: "dotCommand1",
    bindKey: { win: ".", mac: "." },
    exec: function () {
        var pos = editor.selection.getCursor();
        var session = editor.session;

        var curLine = (session.getDocument().getLine(pos.row)).trim();
        var curTokens = curLine.slice(0, pos.column).split(/\s+/);
        var curCmd = curTokens[0];
        if (!curCmd) return;
        var lastToken = curTokens[curTokens.length - 1];

        editor.insert(".");                

        if (lastToken === "foo") {
            // Add your words (bar, baz) to the global word list so that the autocomplete can show both bar, baz
           // Append the words to wordList here
        }
    }
});
```

Inside the Autocompleter we can map the wordList

```
var staticWordCompleter = {
getCompletions: function(editor, session, pos, prefix, callback) {

    callback(null, wordList.map(function(word) {
        return {
            caption: word,
            value: word,
            meta: "static",
            completer: {
                insertMatch: function(editor, data) {
                    var insertedValue = data.value;
                    if(insertedValue === "bar" || insertedValue === "baz") {
                        // You can clear the world list here
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }));
  }
}
editor.completers = [staticWordCompleter];
```

In order to use the Autocompletion always instead of waiting for the user to type the next characters to invoke the autocompletion list you could use the below snippet code during the initialization,

```
editor.commands.on("afterExec", function (e) {
    if (e.command.name == "insertstring" && /^[\w.]$/.test(e.args)) {
        editor.execCommand("startAutocomplete");
    }
});
```

Comment: How do I remove the wordlists? Seems like once I get to `foo.` then forever `bar, baz` would be in `wordList`. Do I need to constantly update `wordList` and remove the autoComplete options??

Comment: You can use the insertMatch option in the completer, which would be invoked once you click on the bar or baz from the autocompletion list, and then you can clear the list. Updated the Answer by adding the insertMatch

Comment: Thanks this works great. Last question. Anyway to actually open the suggestion box automatically on `.` press? Right now you still have to type the next word to get the automcomplete menu to open up. I want on `foo.` as soon as `.` is pressed, the menu to open up

Comment: I'm glad that the solution worked :) And there is no option to invoke the autocompleter actually, it gets invoked when the user actually types something.

Comment: Alright, this is better than nothing. Also, I've noticed, when using your solution, I cannot actually select the completion suggestions (i.e. if I type `foo.b` and then use keyboard to scrolldown to `bar` and press enter, nothing happens; the suggestion bar just closes)

Comment: Hi I've updated the answer, can you please check if it would help you

Comment: it's not working if you're for example in inside the parenthesis of `if`.

Comment: @undefined did not understand what is not working for you, can you explain me in more detail or show a working sample?

Comment: try to use it inside if block, for example: if(foo.

Comment: The lastToken will be "if(foo"

Comment: for some reason this method stopped working in my project